# Modifying Pimple/Slim container

Tags: php, slim, pimple

I would like to be able to modify an array on a Pimple container, however, because the services are frozen by Pimple this seems to be impossible.

I have tried the `extend()` method on the container, however, due to my array not being an object I am unable to modify it.

```
$container = new Slim\Container();
$container['config'] = ['foo'=>'bar'];
// .... do some other stuff.
$container['config']['baz'] = 'Harry'; // throws an error regarding indirect modification
```

Using `extend`

```
$container = new Slim\Container();
$container['config'] = ['foo'=>'bar'];
$container->extend('config',function($config,$container){
    $config['baz'] = 'Harry';
    return $config;
});
// throws an error PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Identifier "config" does not contain an object definition.
```

Is there no way to modify a definition inside Pimple container? Currently I am passing around a `$config` array by reference prior to instantiating the container which is less than ideal!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it turns out that I can just wrap the $config in a function to achieve desired results.

```
$container = new Slim\Container();
$config = ['foo'=>'bar'];
$container['config'] = function($container) use($config){
    return $config;
};
$container->extend('config',function($config,$container) {
    $config['baz']='Harry';
    return $config;
});
print_r($container['config']);
// foo=>bar, baz=>Harry
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by unsetting the container value first.

Pimple freezes values but will allow you to remove them.

```
$container = new Slim\Container();
$container['config'] = ['foo'=>'bar'];
unset($container['config']);
$container->extend('config',function($config,$container){
    $config['baz'] = 'Harry';
    return $config;
});
```

Comment: That would delete the whole value wouldn't it? If yes then that's not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If I delete it then how can I modify it? In short I was trying to merge new with old. Regardless, it's now been achieved.